# what ng-directives to be used when converting a button that uses id

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am working on converting a html to angular js and one of the issue i have is, a button on the page uses ID and based of that id there is a div class that runs set of texts to be displayed accordingly.

Code that we have is something like this.

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn-p10" id="ContinueClicked" aria-controls="doc">Continue</a>
```

From the HTML page when the user clicks on the button continue... below code will be executed.

```
<div class="ContinueClicked">
   text.......
 </div>
```

I am trying to figure out a way to see how i can make it work with angular js. So when the user is clicking on the continue button, the page should display the content in div continueClicked. Should i be using any directive here? please help.

Comment: Did you forget to include the code?

Comment: i intended the code now. You should be able to see it now.

Answer (score 0):

You have to adhere to AngularJS principles and conventions. Angular uses [Directives](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) for most of the DOM transformations, and [Bindings](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/databinding) for constant DOM and Model updates (two-way data bindings.)

In your case scenario you might want to have the following DOM elements (inside a [Controller](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller) inside an `ng-app` [Module](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module), see [AngularJS docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/)):

```
<!-- The button with the event handler as ng-click directive -->
<button ng-click="isContinue = true">Show continue content</button>

<!-- The content wrap with ng-show directive -->
<div class="ContinueClicked" ng-init="isContinue = false" ng-show="isContinue">
    My content to be shown
</div>
```

You can also read and practice basic concepts following the [Angular Tutorial](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial).

Comment: I just tried to modify the code samy way. But nothing seem to happen after i try clicking on the show continue content button.